# Why does an image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices on Android?

Tags: android, image, camera, rotation, android-camera-intent

I'm capturing an image and setting it to image view.

```
public void captureImage() {

    Intent intentCamera = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File filePhoto = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pic.jpg");
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(filePhoto);
    MyApplicationGlobal.imageUri = imageUri.getPath();
    intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intentCamera, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentFromCamera) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentFromCamera);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {

        if (intentFromCamera != null) {
            Bundle extras = intentFromCamera.getExtras();
            if (extras.containsKey("data")) {
                bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            }
            else {
                bitmap = getBitmapFromUri();
            }
        }
        else {
            bitmap = getBitmapFromUri();
        }
        // imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
    else {
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromUri() {

    getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Bitmap bitmap;

    try {
        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri);
        return bitmap;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the problem is, the image on some devices every time it gets rotated. For example, on a Samsung device it works good, but on a [Sony Xperia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Xperia) the image gets rotated by 90 degrees and on [Toshiba Thrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshiba_Thrive) (tablet) by 180 degrees.

Comment: try this in you activity menifest  android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: @nick it doesn't work, now the image gets rotated to 90 degrees rather than 180 degrees on tab

Comment: as i think when you use the internal intent for dealing with the camera app,then it rotates image.This is depends upon how you hold the device to capture image. So you can restrict the user to take image in particular manner means the user will always capture image by holding the device in portrait or landscape.  After that you can change it to specific angle to get image as you want.. OR ANOTHER OPTION, MAKE YOUR OWN CAMERA APP.

Comment: @nick "you can restrict the user to take image in particular manner" means is it same as setting orientation ="potrait"? And how to "After that you can change it to specific angle to get image as you want" achieve? Please can you give some useful links

Comment: I believe the capture intent always brings up the default camera app which has specific orientation on each device and consequently - fixed photo orientation. It does not depend on the way the user hold the device or the orientation of your activity that invoked the intent.

Comment: To avoid Storage permission, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31720143/6131611) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8914291/6131611) answer or [use Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630783/6131611)

Comment: Not exactly duplicate (different list of devices, and different root cause), but highly relevant: *[Images taken with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE always returns 1 for ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION on some Gingerbread devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8450539/192373)*.

Comment: Another relevant edge case: bug on Nexus 5 with some updates for the system camera app, *[Android camera saves photo without ExIf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31171204/192373)*.

Comment: Anyone found any solution for ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED, as on some devices (Android 8 Emulator) image gets rotated whereas on some devices (Android 9 Emulator) it doesn't with the same Orientation value. How to know if the image needs to be rotated or not?

Answer (score 542, accepted):

Most phone cameras are landscape, meaning if you take the photo in portrait, the resulting photos will be rotated 90 degrees. In this case, the camera software should populate the [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) data with the orientation that the photo should be viewed in.

Note that the below solution depends on the camera software/device manufacturer populating the Exif data, so it will work in most cases, but it is not a 100% reliable solution.

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                     ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
switch(orientation) {

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
    default:
        rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
}
```

Here is the `rotateImage` method:

```
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                               matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: From @JasonRobinson code's I learn how to get the actual orientation and by combining with [these code](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2012/05/bitmap-operations-like-re-sizing.html) I'm successfully manage the orientation.

Comment: Second option of `exif.getAttributeInt` using `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED` is almost same, as the second parameter is default value in case the function fails to provide the value.

Comment: This code is for a image already been written to disk, right? I get no results using this method for bitmap about to be written to disk.

Comment: @FatihOzcan looks like `ExitInterface` supports File and InputStream, so you could [create an InputStream](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7698445/291827).

Comment: @Jason Robinson, this code is very useful for getting image from disk and rotating it accordingly but when you are doing a hardwork like i do, i get 4k image from camera and merge it with canvas drawing after scaling drawing from camera preview up to 4k, and save it to disk. Opening a stream again is not efficient, rotating the bitmap with postRotate() method of matix before saving the image sufficient for me. In my case, user should select rotation manually

Comment: @FatihOzcan It should be the same speed regardless of the photo size because it's only reading the Exif headers. It's not reading the pixel data. If you have a Bitmap that you have manually captured, then there would be no Exif data associated with it anyway.

Comment: @Jason Robinson, it should be same speed but opening a stream after saving the bitmap as png or jpeg is extra work. Yes, exactly what i was asking the first place, without saving the image you don't have exif info. I had to rotate image before saving it disk because some models like Nexus 5x have upside down orientation. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: bitmap is an int but rotateImage takes a Bitmap. What should I do?

Comment: @user1744228 you pass in your source Bitmap in that method.

Comment: it works like a charm on my s3 ( kitkat ) note 3 ( lollipop) nexus 5 (marshmallow) but not on my s6edge (nougat ) , can someone tell me why ?

Comment: More here --> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html

Comment: It is always return me 0 value. Please tell how to get actual orientation.

Comment: Getting 0 always, any idea why?

Comment: It crops the image by default when the image orientation actually tooks place inside switch.

Comment: Currently exist any solution?

Comment: what is "photoPath" variable?

Comment: Note: use androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface instead of android.media.ExifInterface

Comment: Using `androidx.exifinterface` works on my own phone and all emulators, but doesn't work on Samsung devices, returning ORIENTATION_NORMAL when taking a photo in portrait, when the value should be ORIENTATION_270. Easy to reproduce on [Samsung's Remote Test Lab](https://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action).

Comment: @lukecross too simple man, it's just path of image..

Comment: Any info about how to use this code, i i am uploading multiple images with for loop ?

Answer (score 224):

By combining *Jason Robinson*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21754321/1364896) with *Felix*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14066265/1364896) and filling the missing parts, **here is the final complete solution for this issue** that will do the following after testing it on Android [Android 4.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.1_Jelly_Bean_.28API_level_16.29) (*Jelly Bean*), [Android 4.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.4_KitKat_.28API_level_19.29) (*KitKat*) and [Android 5.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Lollipop) (*Lollipop*).

**Steps**

1. Scale down the image if it was bigger than 1024x1024.
2. Rotate the image to the right orientation *only* if it was rotate 90, 180 or 270 degree.
3. Recycle the rotated image for memory purposes.

**Here is the code part:**

Call the following method with the current `Context` and the image `URI` that you want to fix

```
/**
 * This method is responsible for solving the rotation issue if exist. Also scale the images to
 * 1024x1024 resolution
 *
 * @param context       The current context
 * @param selectedImage The Image URI
 * @return Bitmap image results
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static Bitmap handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage)
        throws IOException {
    int MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
    int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
    imageStream.close();

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

    img = rotateImageIfRequired(context, img, selectedImage);
    return img;
}
```

Here is the `CalculateInSampleSize` method from the pre mentioned [source](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7ea25fc2bbc54e43616):

```
/**
  * Calculate an inSampleSize for use in a {@link BitmapFactory.Options} object when decoding
  * bitmaps using the decode* methods from {@link BitmapFactory}. This implementation calculates
  * the closest inSampleSize that will result in the final decoded bitmap having a width and
  * height equal to or larger than the requested width and height. This implementation does not
  * ensure a power of 2 is returned for inSampleSize which can be faster when decoding but
  * results in a larger bitmap which isn't as useful for caching purposes.
  *
  * @param options   An options object with out* params already populated (run through a decode*
  *                  method with inJustDecodeBounds==true
  * @param reqWidth  The requested width of the resulting bitmap
  * @param reqHeight The requested height of the resulting bitmap
  * @return The value to be used for inSampleSize
  */
private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee a final image
        // with both dimensions larger than or equal to the requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

        // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
        // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
        // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
        // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
        // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

        final float totalPixels = width * height;

        // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Then comes the method that will check the current image orientation to decide the rotation angle

```
 /**
 * Rotate an image if required.
 *
 * @param img           The image bitmap
 * @param selectedImage Image URI
 * @return The resulted Bitmap after manipulation
 */
private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Context context, Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
ExifInterface ei;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
    ei = new ExifInterface(input);
else
    ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());
        
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            return rotateImage(img, 90);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
            return rotateImage(img, 180);
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
            return rotateImage(img, 270);
        default:
            return img;
    }
}
```

Finally the rotation method itself

```
private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    img.recycle();
    return rotatedImg;
}
```

Comment: the method rotateImageIfRequired() works very well.. thanks !!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Sometimes my phone gives portrait, sometimes landscape photos, but detected orientation is always 0 degrees.

Comment: @Makalele Is this issue also occur while taking photos and attaching through WhatsApp?

Comment: I don't use WhatsApp so I cannot say, but most probably yes. That's because it even happens in stock photo app (Google Stock Camera).

Comment: Kotlin: https://gist.github.com/fada21/feadb8d2feb925a821b6eb233692d31d

Comment: I have images on server. I try to use this code but I have a java.io.FileNotFoundException : No content provider: "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/appli/android_connect/Etablissement/abordage.jpg" after pass uri in parameter of handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap :  url = new URL(myUrlStr); uri = Uri.parse( url.toURI().toString() ); Can you help me about the format of URI ?

Comment: Using `androidx.exifinterface` works on my own phone and all emulators, but doesn't work on Samsung devices, returning ORIENTATION_NORMAL when taking a photo in portrait, when the value should be ORIENTATION_270. Easy to reproduce on [Samsung's Remote Test Lab](https://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action).

Comment: `img.recycle();` in `rotateImage` can cause issues if you pass 0 degrees, as you will be recycling the same bitmap you are returning. I added a check to just return the provided bitmap when degrees is 0.

Comment: Ended up using just your `rotateImageIfRequired` function in concert with my existing functions but works great, thank you!

Answer (score 50):

It's easy to detect the image orientation and replace the bitmap using:

```
 /**
 * Rotate an image if required.
 * @param img
 * @param selectedImage
 * @return
 */
private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Context context,Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) {

    // Detect rotation
    int rotation = getRotation(context, selectedImage);
    if (rotation != 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(rotation);
        Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        img.recycle();
        return rotatedImg;
    }
    else{
        return img;
    }
}

/**
 * Get the rotation of the last image added.
 * @param context
 * @param selectedImage
 * @return
 */
private static int getRotation(Context context,Uri selectedImage) {

    int rotation = 0;
    ContentResolver content = context.getContentResolver();

    Cursor mediaCursor = content.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                       new String[] { "orientation", "date_added" },
                                       null, null, "date_added desc");

    if (mediaCursor != null && mediaCursor.getCount() != 0) {
        while(mediaCursor.moveToNext()){
            rotation = mediaCursor.getInt(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    mediaCursor.close();
    return rotation;
}
```

To avoid Out of memories with big images, I'd recommend you to rescale the image using:

```
private static final int MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
private static final int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage)
    throws IOException {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
    imageStream.close();

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

    img = rotateImageIfRequired(img, selectedImage);
    return img;
}
```

It's not posible to use ExifInterface to get the orientation because an Android OS issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19268

And here is `calculateInSampleSize`

```
/**
 * Calculate an inSampleSize for use in a {@link BitmapFactory.Options} object when decoding
 * bitmaps using the decode* methods from {@link BitmapFactory}. This implementation calculates
 * the closest inSampleSize that will result in the final decoded bitmap having a width and
 * height equal to or larger than the requested width and height. This implementation does not
 * ensure a power of 2 is returned for inSampleSize which can be faster when decoding but
 * results in a larger bitmap which isn't as useful for caching purposes.
 *
 * @param options   An options object with out* params already populated (run through a decode*
 *                  method with inJustDecodeBounds==true
 * @param reqWidth  The requested width of the resulting bitmap
 * @param reqHeight The requested height of the resulting bitmap
 * @return The value to be used for inSampleSize
 */
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee a final image
        // with both dimensions larger than or equal to the requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

        // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
        // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
        // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
        // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
        // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

        final float totalPixels = width * height;

        // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
        final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

        while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Comment: what is calculateInSampleSize method here

Comment: @madhukotagiri here you have an example of implementantion for calculateInSampleSize: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b7ea25fc2bbc54e43616

Comment: Thanks man, you're definitely the one! I'm just wondering how much the resizing will be useful, if the operation is performed just occasionally.

Comment: Uri selectedImage parameter not used in getRotation(...) method. How do we need use it? Thank you.

Comment: `rotateImageIfRequired(img, selectedImage);` you are passing two parameters , whereas  in your method definition you have defined three `private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Context context,Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage)` , What do I pass in as context from my activity?

Comment: Struggled for a while with rotation method since on some device when tacking photo in portrait mode simple rotation makes image stretched. The solution found was: `code 
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postTranslate(-width / 2, -height / 2);
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        matrix.postTranslate(width / 2, height / 2); `

Comment: Parameter 'selectedImage' doesn't seem to be used anywhere. Any reason to be there?

Comment: I reckon we need to use selectedImage otherwise it is not giving proper orientation.

Answer (score 24):

One line solution:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Or

```
Picasso.with(context).load("file:" + photoPath).into(imageView);
```

This will autodetect rotation and place image in correct orientation

Picasso is a very powerful library for handling images in your app includes:
**Complex image transformations with minimal memory use.**

Comment: It just loads the image into a view, it doesn't give you a bitmap or a file you can manipulate or upload to a server.

Comment: Its displaying image clicked as it is. It is not rotating as required.

Comment: @Flawyte you can do that by loading file into target instead of view with callback that returns cropped/resized bitmap:  Picasso.with(this).load(cropUriToLoad.resize(1080, 810).centerInside().into(target); where target = new Target() {
            Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

Comment: the problem i am still facing is it takes few seconds to display image

Comment: not working for me.. this issue exists in Picasso as well

Comment: Nope it doesn't work! Oneplus Android 11 and Samsung Tabs

Answer (score 16):

So first thing, you sholuld know that since Android 7.0 we have to use `FileProvider` and something called `ContentUri`, otherwise you will get an annoying error trying to invoke your `Intent`. This is sample code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getUriFromPath(context, "[Your path to save image]"));
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_RESULT);
```

Method `getUriFromPath(Context, String)` basis on user version of Android create `FileUri (file://...)` or `ContentUri (content://...)` and there it is:

```
public Uri getUriFromPath(Context context, String destination) {
    File file =  new File(destination);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    } else {
        return Uri.fromFile(file);
    }
}
```

After `onActivityResult` you can catch that `uri` where image is saved by camera, but now you have to detect camera rotation, here we will use moddified @Jason Robinson answer:

First we need to create `ExifInterface` based on `Uri`

```
@Nullable
public ExifInterface getExifInterface(Context context, Uri uri) {
    try {
        String path = uri.toString();
        if (path.startsWith("file://")) {
            return new ExifInterface(path);
        }
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            if (path.startsWith("content://")) {
                InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                return new ExifInterface(inputStream);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Above code can be simplified, but i want to show everything. So from `FileUri` we can create `ExifInterface` based on `String path`, but from `ContentUri` we can't, Android doesn't support that.

In that case we have to use other constructor based on `InputStream`. Remember this constructor isn't available by default, you have to add additional library:

```
compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:XX.X.X"
```

Now we can use `getExifInterface` method to get our angle:

```
public float getExifAngle(Context context, Uri uri) {
    try {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = getExifInterface(context, uri);
        if(exifInterface == null) {
            return -1f;
        }

        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return 90f;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return 180f;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return 270f;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return 0f;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                return -1f;
            default:
                return -1f;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1f;
    }
}
```

Now you have Angle to properly rotate you image.

Comment: implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:X.X.X' 
This is for those who are using androidx. thank you for your posting

Answer (score 12):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgFromCameraOrGallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Camera"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGallery"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gallery"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView imgFromCameraOrGallery;
    private Button btnCamera;
    private Button btnGallery;

    private String imgPath;
    final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imgFromCameraOrGallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgFromCameraOrGallery);
        btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        btnGallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGallery);

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                setCapturedImage(getImagePath());
            } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                imgFromCameraOrGallery.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(data.getData())));
            }
        }

    }

    private String getRightAngleImage(String photoPath) {

        try {
            ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
            int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            int degree = 0;

            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    degree = 0;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    degree = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    degree = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    degree = 270;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                    degree = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    degree = 90;
            }

            return rotateImage(degree,photoPath);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return photoPath;
    }

    private String rotateImage(int degree, String imagePath){

        if(degree<=0){
            return imagePath;
        }
        try{
            Bitmap b= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if(b.getWidth()>b.getHeight()){
                matrix.setRotate(degree);
                b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(),
                        matrix, true);
            }

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            String imageName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
            String imageType = imageName.substring(imageName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            if (imageType.equalsIgnoreCase("png")) {
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            }else if (imageType.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")|| imageType.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")) {
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            }
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            b.recycle();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imagePath;
    }

    private void setCapturedImage(final String imagePath){
        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    return getRightAngleImage(imagePath);
                }catch (Throwable e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return imagePath;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String imagePath) {
                super.onPostExecute(imagePath);
                imgFromCameraOrGallery.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(imagePath));
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
        try {
            // Decode deal_image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            int scale = 1;
            while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
                scale *= 2;
            // Decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            String id = "";
            if(uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":").length > 1)
                id = uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[1];
            else if(uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":").length > 0)
                id = uri.getLastPathSegment().split(":")[0];
            if(id.length() > 0){
                final String[] imageColumns = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                final String imageOrderBy = null;
                Uri tempUri = getUri();
                Cursor imageCursor = getContentResolver().query(tempUri, imageColumns, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=" + id, null, imageOrderBy);
                if (imageCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
                }else{
                    return null;
                }
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        }else{
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else
                return null;
        }

    }

    private Uri getUri() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if(!state.equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            return MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        return MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    public Uri setImageUri() {
        Uri imgUri;
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/",getString(R.string.app_name) + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".png");
            imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }else {
            File file = new File(getFilesDir() ,getString(R.string.app_name) + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+ ".png");
            imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        return imgUri;
    }

    public String getImagePath() {
        return imgPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can just read the orientation of the camera sensor like indicated by Google in the documentation: *https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html*

```
SENSOR_ORIENTATION

Added in API level 21
Key<Integer> SENSOR_ORIENTATION
Clockwise angle through which the output image needs to be rotated to be upright on the device screen in its native orientation.

Also defines the direction of rolling shutter readout, which is from top to bottom in the sensor's coordinate system.

Units: Degrees of clockwise rotation; always a multiple of 90

Range of valid values:
0, 90, 180, 270

This key is available on all devices.
```

Sample code:

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
int orientation = 0;
try {
    String cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];
    CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
    orientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: this should be marked as the answer. Rotation is resulted from the camera orientation so this is awesome!

Comment: How do you know which camera took the picture and whether the phone is still in the same orientation as when the user took the picture?

Answer (score 7):

Jason Robinson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14066265/5555218) and Sami Eltamawy [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31720143/5555218) are excelent.

Just an improvement to complete the aproach, you should use compat ExifInterface.

`com.android.support:exifinterface:${lastLibVersion}`

You will be able to instantiate the ExifInterface(pior API <24) with `InputStream` (from `ContentResolver`) instead of uri paths avoiding "File not found exceptions"

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html

Answer (score 5):

I created a Kotlin extension function that simplifies the operation for Kotlin developers based on @Jason Robinson's answer. I hope it helps.

```
fun Bitmap.fixRotation(uri: Uri): Bitmap? {

    val ei = ExifInterface(uri.path)

    val orientation: Int = ei.getAttributeInt(
        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED
    )

    return when (orientation) {
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 -> rotateImage( 90f)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 -> rotateImage( 180f)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 -> rotateImage( 270f)
        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL -> this
        else -> this
    }
}

fun Bitmap.rotateImage(angle: Float): Bitmap? {
    val matrix = Matrix()
    matrix.postRotate(angle)
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(
        this, 0, 0, width, height,
        matrix, true
    )
}
```

Comment: awesome but suffers from the same issue as all solutions, as extension or a function - doesn't work on Android 10.

Comment: In my case it works fine on Android 10.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Android 11, One plus device. I receive `ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED` sure from metadata, but then it rotates my image to further 90 degree and image goes upside down. I noticed this issue creates Left or right rotations by default, hence in my code it went upside-down on automatic rotation.

Answer (score 5):

I solved it using a different method. All you have to do is check if the width is greater than height

```
Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
if(finalBitmap.getWidth() >= finalBitmap.getHeight()){
    rotationMatrix.setRotate(-90);
}else{
    rotationMatrix.setRotate(0);
}

Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap,0,0,finalBitmap.getWidth(),finalBitmap.getHeight(),rotationMatrix,true);
```

Comment: In my case I  need :   rotationMatrix.setRotate(90);

Answer (score 5):

here a solution that is based on the ones above but only needs context and the image file as inputs

```
public static Bitmap rectifyImage(Context context,File imageFile){
    Bitmap originalBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try{
        Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        ExifInterface ei;
        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 23)
            ei = new ExifInterface(input);
        else
            ei = new ExifInterface(uri.getPath());

        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return rotateImage(originalBitmap, 90);
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return rotateImage(originalBitmap, 180);
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return rotateImage(originalBitmap, 270);
            default:
                return originalBitmap;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        return originalBitmap;
    }
}

public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
            matrix, true);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Normally it is recommended to solve the problem with the [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html), like @Jason Robinson did suggest. If this approach doesn't work, you could try to look up the [Orientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html#ORIENTATION) of the latest image taken...

```
private int getImageOrientation(){
    final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
    final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));
        cursor.close();
        return orientation;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this code only detects in what degree rotation occurred. Now I'm able to do that, but unable in next task i.e. to rotate the image.

Comment: You're right, but you didn't ask for the rotation in this Thread, so let's keep it clean ;) That's why I put my answer to your rotating problem into your other Thread... Hope that helps, it does work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123809/code-to-rotate-image-captured-by-camera-intent-not-working-in-android

Comment: `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION` available only in Android 10 and upwards.

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, @jason-robinson answer above didn't work for me.

Although the rotate function works perfectly:

```
public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix,
            true);
}
```

I had to do the following to get the orientation as the Exif orientation was always 0

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] orientationColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.ORIENTATION};
            Cursor cur = managedQuery(imageUri, orientationColumn, null, null, null);
            int orientation = -1;
            if (cur != null && cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    orientation = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(orientationColumn[0]));
            }
            InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            switch(orientation) {
                    case 90:
                            bitmap = rotateImage(chosen_image_bitmap, 90);
                            break;
                    case 180:
                            bitmap = rotateImage(chosen_image_bitmap, 180);
                            break;
                    case 270:
                            bitmap = rotateImage(chosen_image_bitmap, 270);
                            break;
                    default:
                            break;
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap );
```

Comment: alwasys 0, samsung 7

Answer (score 3):

The selected answer uses the most common method answered to this and similar questions. However, it does not work with both front and back cameras on Samsung. For those looking for a solution which works across both front and back cameras for Samsung and other major manufacturers, this answer by nvhausid is awesome:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18915443/6080472

For those who don't want to click through, the relevant magic is to use the CameraInfo rather then relying on EXIF.

```
Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(mCurrentCameraId, info);
Bitmap bitmap = rotate(realImage, info.orientation);
```

Full code in the link.

Comment: no, wrong rotation in different angles (smasung s7). I mean gallery of course

Answer (score 2):

If somebody experiences problems with `ExifInterface` on [Android 4.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.4_KitKat_.28API_level_19.29) (KitKat) for getting the orientation, it might be because of wrong **path** got from the URI. See a solution for propoer `getPath` in Stack Overflow question *[Get real path from URI, Android KitKat new storage access framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067508/get-real-path-from-uri-android-kitkat-new-storage-access-framework/20559175#20559175)*

Comment: This one comment is what I needed. Dude, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Better try to take the picture in a specific orientation.

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

For best results give landscape orientation in the cameraview activity.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. In-fact on tab, every time after finishing execution of onActivityResult, strangely onCreate gets called.

Comment: sorry, the problem is as it is

Answer (score 1):

This maybe goes without saying but always remember that you can handle some of these image handling issues on your server. I used responses like the ones contained in this thread to handle the immediate display of the image. However my application requires images to be stored on the server (this is probably a common requirement if you want the image to persist as users switch phones).

The solutions contained in many of the threads concerning this topic don't discuss the lack of persistence of the EXIF data which doesn't survive the Bitmap's image compression, meaning you'll need to rotate the image each time your server loads it. Alternatively, you can send the EXIF orientation data to your server, and then rotate the image there if needed.

It was easier for me to create a permanent solution on a server because I didn't have to worry about Android's clandestine file paths.

Comment: Can you rotate it once at image capture time and save it that way so it never needs to be rotated again?

Comment: Yea you can and that's actually the process I ended up implementing in the end. I was having trouble getting the file path from the image on the Android phone that would allow me to do that. This is the answer that helped: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36714242/5443056

Comment: 1000s apps that can rotate image on a phone, rotate them on server instead. Every situation is different, but I would run away from solution that puts work on your server.  You always want to outsource computing to customer phones when possible.

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked with me, it got the bitmap from the fileUri, and do the rotation fixing if required:

```
    private fun getCapturedImage(selectedPhotoUri: Uri): Bitmap {
        val bitmap = when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28 -> MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                this.contentResolver,
                selectedPhotoUri
            )
            else -> {
                val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPhotoUri)
                ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
            }
        }

        // If the image is rotated, fix it
        return when (ExifInterface(contentResolver.run { openInputStream(selectedPhotoUri) }).getAttributeInt(
            ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED)) {
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90 ->
                Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Matrix().apply {
                    postRotate(90F) }, true)
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180 ->
                Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Matrix().apply {
                    postRotate(180F) }, true)
            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270 ->
                Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height, Matrix().apply {
                    postRotate(270F) }, true)
            else -> bitmap
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `Xamarin.Android` version:

From @Jason Robinson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14066265/3367974):

```
Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, int angle)
{
    var matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.PostRotate(angle);

    return Bitmap.CreateBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height, matrix, true);
}

Bitmap rotateIfRequired(Bitmap bitmap, string imagePath)
{
    var ei = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
    var orientation = ei.GetAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TagOrientation, (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Undefined);

    switch (orientation)
    {
        case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate90: return rotate(bitmap, 90);
        case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate180: return rotate(bitmap, 180);
        case (int)Android.Media.Orientation.Rotate270: return rotate(bitmap, 270);
        default: return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Then `calculateInSampleSize` method:

```
int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqW, int reqH)
{
    float h = options.OutHeight;
    float w = options.OutWidth;
    var inSampleSize = 1;

    if (h > reqH || w > reqW)
    {
        if (reqH == 0) inSampleSize = (int)Math.Floor(w / reqW);
        else if (reqW == 0) inSampleSize = (int)Math.Floor(h / reqH);
        else
        {
            var hRatio = (int)Math.Floor(h / reqH);
            var wRatio = (int)Math.Floor(w / reqW);
            inSampleSize = false ? Math.Max(hRatio, wRatio) : Math.Min(hRatio, wRatio);
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

From @Sami Eltamawy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31720143/3367974):

```
Bitmap handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(string imagePath)
{
    var maxHeight = 1024;
    var maxWidth = 1024;

    var options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath, options);

    options.InSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, maxWidth, maxHeight);

    options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;

    var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(imagePath, options);

    bitmap = rotateIfRequired(bitmap, imagePath);

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the rotation issue on my xamarin. android app. The problem is when using back camera the image gets saved on 90 degree right. But using front camera it saves on 90 degree left. So the rotation solve using this code working only on front camera. Did you faced the issue?

Comment: Hello, I think that's because front camera is flipped by default. if you turns that off, the result of this code for both camera are equal?

Comment: Hi, Can you help me on that part? I have asked a question here. But still in the dark. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278491/camera-capture-image-rotate-to-portrait-xamarin-android/64294447?noredirect=1#comment113703379_64294447

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Fresco, you can use this -

```
final ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)
.setRotationOptions(RotationOptions.autoRotate())
.build();

mSimpleDraweeView.setController(
Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
    .setImageRequest(imageRequest)
    .build());
```

This automatically rotates the images based on Exif data.

Source: https://frescolib.org/docs/rotation.html

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer for this problem without using **ExifInterface**. We can get the rotation of the camera either front camera or back camera whichever you are using then while creating the Bitmap we can rotate the bitmap using **Matrix.postRotate(degree)**

```
public int getRotationDegree() {
    int degree = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
            degree = info.orientation;

            return degree;
        }
    }

    return degree;
}
```

After calculating the rotation you can rotate you bitmap like below:

```
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

 matrix.postRotate(getRotationDegree());

 Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Herare **bm** should be your bitmap.

If you want to know the rotation of your front camera just change **Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK** to **Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT** above.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Horrible answer but I accidentally upvoted. This code assumes every image from your gallery is made with _your_ camera. This is not the case

Comment: @Zun The question asked is for image capturing and not for picking image from gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Use of [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) worked for me. Rotation is taken cared of automatically.

```
Bitmap bitmap = Glide.with(myContext).asBitmap().load(imageFilePath).submit(SIZE_ORIGINAL, SIZE_ORIGINAL).get();
```

Then you save that bitmap to a file in JPEG format, for example.

If you just want to load into an `ImageView` instead of saving to a file:

```
Glide.with(myContext).load(imageFilePath).into(myImageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

by using glide lib you can get image with exact orientation not need to check rotation

in kotlin

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
         var bitmap = Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(imagePathOrUriOrLink)
                /*.apply(
                    RequestOptions()
                        .override(MAXIMUM_IMAGE_RESOLUTION)
                )*/ //uncomment it if you want original image
                /*.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache(true)*/ //uncomment it you want to not cache image
                .submit().get()//this is synchronous approach  
}
```

using this dependency

```
api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```