# How to set captured images in portrait mode

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on a application in which I have given facility to user that he can take a picture using his mobile camera and then I am displaying the image in a Imageview.

Now the problem is that if I am capturing the image in a portrait mode or in landscape mode it is always setting the image in landscape mode in ImageView, but I want the image to be set in portrait mode only. Please help me out with this problem.

Any help would be appreciable...

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Matrix mat = new Matrix();

ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(yourimagepath);
String orientstring = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
int orientation = orientstring != null ? Integer.parseInt(orientstring) : ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL;
int rotateangle = 0;
if(orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) 
            rotateangle = 90;
if(orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) 
            rotateangle = 180;
if(orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) 
            rotateangle = 270;

mat.setRotate(rotateangle, (float) bmpPic.getWidth() / 2, (float) bmpPic.getHeight() / 2);

File f = new File(yourimagepath);       
Bitmap bmpPic = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null); 
Bitmap bmpPic1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpPic, 0, 0, bmpPic.getWidth(), bmpPic.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

Comment: ,Thanks for your answer but how to add mat value to bitmap can you please post code snippet for this

Comment: Can you please post it I am unable to do this

Answer (score 2):

use like that

```
Matrix matrix=new Matrix();
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

for exp:

```
matrix.postRotate( 90f, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2, imageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2)
```

Comment: what should be angle, pivX and pivY here?

Comment: sorry didn't see the example

Comment: mouse over on postRotate() in eclipse the you can see the details easily

Answer (score -1):

Here is a great solution I came across for this:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/34241250/8033090

One line solution:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

or

```
Picasso.with(context).load("file:" + photoPath).into(imageView);
```

This will autodetect rotation and place image in correct orientation

Picasso is a very powerful library for handling images in your app includes: Complex image transformations with minimal memory use. It can take a second to load but I just put some text behind the image view that says "Loading image" and when the image loads it covers the text.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16252863)

Comment: @suraj Thanks for the advice I have updated my post.