# Intent to a new page when an image is selected

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, whatsapp

Currently I create an app which has the camera function that allows users to select their image or do capturing.I get the tutorial from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22165449/5261462. But I want the selected image intent to another page **instead of just displaying on imageView**. The image need to fix the screen and can add caption at below like **whatsapp.**

This is what I've tried so far.

Everything start from **Project1.java**, with the `imagebutton`.

```
 public void addListenerOnButton() {

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ImageFitScreen i = new ImageFitScreen();
                i.selectImage();
            }

        });

    }
```

**ImageFitScreen.java**

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.image_fit_screen);

            b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText38);
            u = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText39);
        }

        public void selectImage() {

            final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageFitScreen.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                       File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                       intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                       startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
   }
                     else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                      {
                        Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                       startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                       }
                       else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       }
                       }
                         });

            builder.show();

        }
```

**image_fit_screen**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="574dp"
        android:layout_height="523dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_x="6dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="388dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText38"
        android:layout_x="8dp"
        android:layout_y="435dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="386dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText39"
        android:hint="Add a caption"
        android:layout_x="2dp"
        android:layout_y="410dp" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

But I get error as below when the `imageButton` in **Project1.java** is clicked.

> 11-03 11:44:44.800  31219-31219/com.example.project.project
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 31219
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:164)
>               at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:108)
>               at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog$Builder.(AlertDialog.java:269)
>               at com.example.project.project.ImageFitScreen.selectImage(ImageFitScreen.java:77)
>               at com.example.project.project.Project1$2.onClick(Project1.java:80)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)

**(ImageFitScreen.java:77)**

> AlertDialog.Builder builder = new
>   AlertDialog.Builder(ImageFitScreen.this);

**(Project1.java:80)**

> i.selectImage();

I am seriously in dire need of some advice. Can someone please please assist me with some advice. PLEASE : )?

Comment: [Check](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA)

Comment: ImageFitScreen is it an activity?

Comment: @FabinPaul Ya..my idea is move all the code from `selectimage` to a new class and using new layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, ImageFitScreen is an activity and should be started using an Intent i.e.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Project1.this,ImageFitScreen.class);
startActivity(i);
```

If you look at the exception, it tells you that context is null ie. **ImageFitScreen.this** is null at the line

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageFitScreen.this);
```

This is because, activity will only have a context if it is started by the activitymanager. We use intent to ask activitymanger to start an activity. Hope it helps you.

**UPDATE:**

You can use ImageFitScreen to hold imageview and edittext for caption. Then start ImageFitScreeen when you need the user to pick an image. And onCreate of ImageFitScreen you can start selectImage() function ie.

Project1.java

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Project1.this,ImageFitScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });

}
```

ImageFitScreen.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_fit_screen);

        b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText38);
        u = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText39);

        selectImage();
    }

    public void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from             Gallery","Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageFitScreen.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                   File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                  }
                 else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
                  {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
                   }
                   else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
                   finish();
                   }
                   }
                     });
        builder.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                finish();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
        builder.show();

    }
```

Comment: But how about if I want to do something like whatsapp? It will allow us to pick image from gallery. Once the image get selected, it will show the selected image in full screen and can add caption

Comment: Yes bro, is what I looking for. But when I click the `cancel` in the dialog box, it shows `ImageFitScreen` instead of `Project1.java`

Comment: bro, you can always use finish() to finish an activity. :) I have edited my answer...

Comment: how about use the return button that provided by the emulator? Do I need to add  `public void onBackPressed()`?

Comment: bro, I have edited my answer. This is one of the options. But I think user can still cancel/dismiss alertdialog by click outside it. Another solution is disabling this by added the code    `builder.setCancelable(false);`

Comment: or you can use `builder.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

Comment: Thanks bro, it works like charm :) Why the captured image always shows landscape?

Comment: I guess that is device specific and also depends on the orientation with which you captured the image. Try a different test device.. You can also refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083366/how-to-set-captured-images-in-portrait-mode). Hope it helps you..

Comment: If the user already in gallery and he wishes to return, how can it straight away back to `Project1.java` instead of `ImageFitScreen`

Comment: In that case, onActivityResult resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED. In such case you can simple finish the activity.

Comment: Did you mean onActivityResult in ImageFitScreen?