# ExifInterface not returning the correct orientation (Samsung Galaxy S3)

Tags: android, android-image, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to identify the orientation of the image using:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_path);
int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
```

I'm not sure if it's working correctly. Here's why:
I take an image of a paper on my desk with "Portrait" orientation. My phone is in a plane parallel to the desk. However, the phone saves the image, **rotated counter-clockwise 90 degrees.**

I don't know why it does that, but regardless, I expect my **exifOrientation** to be 6, so that I could use this to rotate my image:

```
switch (exifOrientation) {
        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
            rotate = 90;
            break;
        ...
        ...
}
```

However, my **exifOrientation** is **1** and the image does not get correctly rotated.

I have looked at :
[Why does an image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android)

and even tried:

```
private int getImageOrientation(){
final String[] imageColumns = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION };
final String imageOrderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID+" DESC";
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        imageColumns, null, null, imageOrderBy);

if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    int orientation = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION));
    cursor.close();
    return orientation;
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

To reiterate, I'm trying to identify the correct orientation.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?