# Why portrait images from gallery are being saved to Parse as landscape?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, image-uploading, image-rotation

I found the below code from the [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android) of *@Haresh Chhelana* and modified it a little, in order to rotate the photo chose from gallery OR taken by the camera using Android mobile phone, before saving it to [**Parse**](https://parse.com/) cloud.

---

When I take a picture from camera, with landscape or portrait orientation, it is always looking correct as I checked it from Parse.

When I choose a landscape photo from gallery the photo is being saved correctly again.

**BUT**, when I try to save a portrait photo, the photo is being saved *landscape*.

Note that in my manifest I have those lines, so that my application always run in portrait orientation (I don't know if this has something to do with the problem):

`android:configChanges="orientation"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

---

Those are the listeners for the buttons that the user press when he wants to upload a picture from gallery or take a new picture:

```
picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);
                    flag_photo = true;
                    }
            });

            camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                }
            });
```

---

The way I save the photo in one of my functions:

```
ParseFile file = null;

            file = new ParseFile("profile_picture.jpg", image);

            // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
            file.saveInBackground();

            user.put("photo", file);
```

---

The OnActivityResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
                rotateImage(getImagePath());
            } else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
//                imgFromCameraOrGallery.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(data.getData())));

                // Convert it to byte
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getAbsolutePath(data.getData())).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                image = stream.toByteArray();

            }
            flag_photo = true;
        }
        else
            flag_photo = false;
    }
```

---

The RotateImage function :

```
  private void rotateImage(final String path) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap b = decodeFileFromPath(path);
                try {
                    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(path);
                    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    switch (orientation) {
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                            matrix.postRotate(90);
                            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                            matrix.postRotate(180);
                            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            break;
                        case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                            matrix.postRotate(270);
                            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            break;
                        default:
                            b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                try {
                    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
                    }
                    else {
                        file = new File(getFilesDir() , "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".jpg");
                    }
                    out1 = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out1);

                    // Convert it to byte
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

                    // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
                    image = stream.toByteArray();

                    //imgFromCameraOrGallery.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        out1.close();
                    } catch (Throwable ignore) {

                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

---

And this is the DecodeFileFromPath:

```
 private Bitmap decodeFileFromPath(String path){
        Uri uri = getImageUri(path);
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            //Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);
            in.close();


            int scale = 1;
            int inSampleSize = 1024;
            if (o.outHeight > inSampleSize || o.outWidth > inSampleSize) {
                scale = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(inSampleSize / (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o2);
            in.close();

            return b;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

---

I also have those functions if you want to see their code. I haven't post them because my question became too long and I don't believe that I can change something in them to solve my problem:
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android  NOTE all answer... there are more than one technique for rotations. U r using wrong one to check if rotate is need.

Comment: I checked the link you send me and the one that the answer was navigated us to. I tried all the possible ways I found and at the end the only whole example was from @Haresh Chhelana . So, I changed completely the way that I was even uploaded the picture but still no rotation. I will post my code above and check it please if you want.