# Image gets rotate though the orientation is 0 using exif while selecting from gallery

Tags: android, image, bitmap, rotation, exif

I am selecting an image from gallery and showing it on a image view. Image is getting selected, but on samsung phones it has issue of rotating the image so to solve that I am checking if the image is rotated or not usif EXIF interface and if rotated change its angle.

But this is not working for some images. Some images I can see straight, but some images if they are straight then also they are getting rotate.

As I did debug the orientation for the image is 0, it goes in the default case and applies normal bitmap to the rotated bitmap. Still the image I see is rotated. Not getting why is this happening..

```
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,512,512, true);

    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, bytes);
    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    loadImageFromFile(destination.getAbsolutePath());

}



public void loadImageFromFile(String imageFile){

    try {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(imageFile);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile);

            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
            Log.e("orientation",String.valueOf(orientation)+" check");
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                    Log.e("orientation",String.valueOf(orientation)+" check");
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                    Log.e("orientation",String.valueOf(orientation)+" check");
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                    Log.e("orientation",String.valueOf(orientation)+" check");
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
                    Log.e("orientation",String.valueOf(orientation)+" check");
                    break;

                default:
                    rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
                    Log.e("orientation",String.valueOf(orientation)+" check");
                    break;
            }

        if(rotatedBitmap != null)
        {
            profile_image.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
            selectedBitmap = rotatedBitmap;

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); //replace 100 with desired quality percentage.
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("temp",null, getCacheDir());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
                fos.write(byteArray);

                mProfileImage = tempFile;
        }

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      //  UiUtils.showAlert(getString(R.string.error),NewGroupAcvitity.this);
    }
}

public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix,
            true);
}
```

EDIT:

-

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
-    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
-
-        Uri uri = (Uri)data.getData();
-        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
-        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
-        if(cursor != null) {
-            cursor.moveToFirst();
-            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
-            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
-            cursor.close();
-
-            loadImageFromFile(picturePath);
-        }
-    }
```

@greenapps - use selected file like this? I tried this, but this was not working in xiaomi devices so I changed the code. Is there any other way for other devices?

What's going wrong here? Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Comment: where does "bitmap" in "rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);" come from?

Comment: The code does not work for xiaomi. Ok. But does it work for samsung? You are unclear.

Comment: works on samsung I can see straight image. But in xiaomi the cursor returns null so I can't select the image. @greenapps

Comment: As had been said before: You should use a different `ExifInterface` class which can read the file contens from an input stream for the file. `Uri uri = (Uri)data.getData();`. Hence you could use `InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` Read stackoverflow as CommonsWare has told before which class you can use.

Comment: I did not get it. Can you please show an example? @greenapps

Comment: No. As i do not work with that other ExifInterface class. You better google for it and read @CommonsWare blog about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
loadImageFromFile(destination.getAbsolutePath());
```

The image that you try to load is originally from a bitmap which you compressed to jpg and saved to file. `destination` is the `File` object for that file.

Bitmaps do not contain exif information. And hence your jpg file will not contain an exif too.

So it is useless to use `ExifInterface` on it.

Sid i saw this code before. And told the same story. Maybe it was even you which i told it.

Comment: I dont know, I have posted the question todday. but same I am doing for camera and its working for it. Then how to solve this issue for samsung devices. @greenapps

Comment: The posted code cannot work to begin with. Not on a single device. Because bitmaps do not contain exif info.

Comment: If you want to determine the orientation with exif info from a jpg file selected with the gallery app then use that file djrectly. Do not convert the file to bitmap first and then resave to a different file without exif info.

Comment: If you need a bitmap to display in an imageview and you want to rotate that bitmap and need exif info then use the original file to extract exif info from. Not from a file which you created from that bitmap.

Comment: `I dont know, I have posted the question todday.`. Well we could call that a lie. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172441/rotate-image-taken-from-camera-or-gallery You are struggling so long already and do have a habit of not answering questions and leaving the scene instead.

Comment: It was solved that time, again I got problem for xiaomi devices, while trying to solve that issue again I came to this  error. :-( @greenapps

Comment: thank you this worked for this error but yet to test on xiaomi device, may be any other way to select images for xiaomi devices? @greenapps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127790/discussion-between-sid-and-greenapps).