# Image is rotated when rendered

Tags: html, css, angularjs, firebase-storage

I'm having an issue with some images. I'm creating a posts web module and users are allowed to upload their images. Everything is working fine, the problem is when rendering the image.
The image is uploaded in the correct orientation (portrait) but it's being rendered in landscape orientation, and as this is happening with just some of the images, I can't use css rotation to fix this or something that would affect the ones that are being rendered correctly.

```
<post ng-repeat="post in $ctrl.posts">
    <div class="image__container">
        <img ng-src="{{ post.displayImg }}" alt="{{ post.altName }}">
    </div>
</post>
```

The uploading process is done via the firebase storage API, following the example code of the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files), and everything is working correctly in that matter, the only issue is when rendering some of the images.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add your code, othervise it is impossible to help

Comment: This is usually a result of uploading images taken on a mobile device. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android

Comment: Thanks, I fixed this with [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) with ngf-fix-orientation

Comment: I added ngf-fix-orientation="true" on input type="file" but don't rotate in correct orientation in thumbnail. Why?