# Why I have this rotation of image?

Tags: android, picasso

in my app I need to load image from camera.

This is the code I've used:

```
private void openCamera()
{
    mMediaUri =getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    Intent photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    photoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
    startActivityForResult(photoIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);


}


private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int mediaTypeImage)
{
    //check for external storage
    if(isExternalStorageAvaiable())
    {
        File mediaStorageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        String fileName = "";
        String fileType = "";
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new java.util.Date());

        fileName = "IMG_"+timeStamp;
        fileType = ".jpg";

        File mediaFile;
        try
        {
            mediaFile = File.createTempFile(fileName,fileType,mediaStorageDir);
            Log.i("st","File: "+Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("St","Error creating file: " + mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() +fileName +fileType);
            return null;
        }
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", mediaFile);
    }
    //something went wrong
    return null;

}

private boolean isExternalStorageAvaiable()
{
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }


}

   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

   if(resultCode == DIALOG_CODE)
    {
        String s = data.getStringExtra("choose");

        if(s.equals(getString(R.string.takephoto)))
        {
          openCamera();
        }
        else if(s.equals(getString(R.string.library)))
        {
          openGallery();
        }
    }
    else if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO) //dalla fotocamera
        {
            if (data != null)  //caso galleria
            {
                mMediaUri = data.getData();
            }

            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(mMediaUri).resize(1280, 1280).transform(new RoundedTransformation()).centerCrop().into(photo, new Callback()
            {
                public void onSuccess()
                {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {

                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

and it works but it gives me this error: if I take a photo like this:
[image]

it loads a picture in imageview in this way:
[image]

but if I load the picture from the gallery, it works ok.

What's the error here?
Thanks

Comment: You have to rotate Image with `ExifInterface` Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to rotate image using `ExifInterface`.

Image rotate based on image capture angle.

`ExifInterface` will rotate image even if you click photo from any angle.

 It will display properly.

```
    File mediaFile = new File(mediaPath);
            Bitmap bitmap;
            if (mediaFile.exists()) {

                if (isImage(mediaPath)) {

                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    int height = (myBitmap.getHeight() * 512 / myBitmap.getWidth());
                    Bitmap scale = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap, 512, height, true);
                    int rotate = 0;
                    try {
                        exif = new ExifInterface(mediaFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                            ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                    switch (orientation) {
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                        rotate = 0;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                        rotate = 270;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                        rotate = 180;
                        break;
                    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                        rotate = 90;
                        break;
                    }

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(rotate);
                    Bitmap rotateBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scale, 0, 0, scale.getWidth(),
                            scale.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                    displayImage.setImageBitmap(rotateBitmap);
       }
}
public static boolean isImage(String str) {
        boolean temp = false;
        String[] arr = { ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".bmp", ".gif" };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            temp = str.endsWith(arr[i]);
            if (temp) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: What's the error there in His code?

Comment: He want to display image proper. currently image display rotate.

Comment: Why image got rotated? Specify that reason in your answer Is that Device Specific ?

Comment: No this is not device specific. It is depend on click angle of photo.

Comment: You are not completely correct. ExifInterface is a class for reading and writing Exif tags in a JPEG file or a RAW image file. Most phone cameras are landscape, meaning if you take the photo in portrait, the resulting photos will be rotated 90 degrees. In this case, the camera software should populate the `Exif Data` with the orientation that the photo should be viewed in.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: Add that to your answer to help the OP and future readers [**#soreadytohelp**](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23soreadytohelp&lang=en) :-)

Comment: @MaňishYadav so ExitInterface could give wrong rotation?

Comment: @ste9206 Practically to me the above **code doesn't work 100% for all the Mobile Devices** for more information on this refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a)