# How to make "Select Image From Gallery or Camera" in Android

Tags: android, image, select, camera, gallery

I want to make "Select Image From Gallery or Camera". You can say there are a lot of library on the internet for this. I know but I have an another problem. I can make both select images from gallery and camera capture. But camera resulted in image rotated after the capture. I [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a) the problem with rotating. Now I want to show an imageview that image. Some devices didn't show the image in imageview(Samsung Note 3 Android version 5.0). I made a lot of searches and find advice. I applied the recommendations. But I can not solve that problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem happened with me. I am not able to see captured images on Samsung and MI devices mostly.

By using this library I have solved my issue.

https://github.com/coomar2841/android-multipicker-library

Answer (score 2):

It might be too late for the answer but I hope it will help others.

Instead of using external libraries it is better to create your own layout and use it.

Step 1: Create layout for options.

> image_choose_bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvClickImageText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_vector_camera_icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Take Photo"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvChooseGalleryText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvChooseGalleryText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_vector_gallery_icon"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Choose Image"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tvClickImageText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvClickImageText"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tvClickImageText" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Step 2: Create a BottomSheetDialog where you can inflate the layout and configure it.

> DialogImageChooser.java

```
public class DialogImageChooser extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}

View view;
//    DialogNationalitySelectionBinding mBinding;
Context mContext;
private bottomSheetListener mListener;
TextView tvClickImageText, tvChooseGalleryText;

public DialogImageChooser() {
}

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public DialogImageChooser(@NonNull Context context, bottomSheetListener mListener) {
    this.mListener = mListener;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_choose_bottom_sheet, container, false);

    tvClickImageText = view.findViewById(R.id.tvClickImageText);
    tvChooseGalleryText = view.findViewById(R.id.tvChooseGalleryText);

    tvClickImageText.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mListener.onCardClicked("camera");
        dismiss();
    });

    tvChooseGalleryText.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        mListener.onCardClicked("gallery");
        dismiss();
    });

    return view;
}


public interface bottomSheetListener {
    void onCardClicked(String option);
}
}
```

Step 3: Finally in the Activity just make a call for Dialog.

> YourActivity.java

```
ivItemImage.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        new DialogImageChooser(YourActivity.this, selectedOption -> {
            if (selectedOption.equalsIgnoreCase("camera")) {
                TakePictureIntent(CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else if (selectedOption.equalsIgnoreCase("gallery")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, SELECT_IMAGE);
            }
        }).show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "add_photo_dialog");
    });
```

That's it. Custom "Select Image From Gallery or Camera Dialog" is integrated without use of any external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

On which version of android image is not shown in imageview

If it is Android N
you give provider in Manifest

add this code to your manifest

```
  <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:theme="@style/MyAppTheme">
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

provider_paths is in resource-xml folder

Comment: Samsung Note 3, Android version 5.0

Comment: This does not correspond to the question, it serves to share files of your application, not to select an image

Answer (score 0):

So that the user can choose an image of the gallery do this in your Activity :

The method that shows the gallery :

```
 private static final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1;

 public void showGallery() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");       
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
    }
```

And this will be called when the user picks one image, the image path, if any, will be stored in `imagePath`

```
private String imagePath;

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            imagePath = "";
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);

                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
                    //Here you can call a method that loads the image and 
                    //show it in an ImageView
                }
            }
        }
```

you will need a permission in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```