# How to set image without rotating

Tags: imageview

I am capturing image and setting to image view. It works fine for me. But the problem is When I'm setting the image to an ImageView it is getting rotated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can u post your code??\

Comment: See this url may help you...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a

Comment: posting code will help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `compile 'com.kbeanie:multipicker:1.1.1@aar'` library for solving this problem

Answer (score 2):

Use this...

```
public static Bitmap changeOrientation(Bitmap bitmap, String imagePath) throws IOException {
    ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(imagePath);
    int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    switch (orientation) {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        return rotate(bitmap, 90);

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        return rotate(bitmap, 180);

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        return rotate(bitmap, 270);

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
        return flip(bitmap, true, false);

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
        return flip(bitmap, false, true);

    default:
        return bitmap;
    }
}

public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap bitmap, float degree) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(degree);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}

public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap bitmap, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preScale(horizontal ? -1 : 1, vertical ? -1 : 1);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

Comment: Perfect Answer!