# Bitmap rotates image 90 degrees after taken from Camera in my own app

Tags: java, android

I set an image I took with my phone's camera into an imageView but it changes its orientation to 90 degrees. If I check the image in my phone it is just in portrait mode and if I put it in the Imageview it changes to landscape mode.

Code where I set the image on my ImageView:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);

        Bitmap bt=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 800, false);

        imgView.setImageBitmap(bt);
```

Comment: Please look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a

Comment: maybe your imageView has a tag in it or in its parent called "android:rotation="90" " .. please share the xml of that imageView of yours

Comment: Do some research before asking questions

Answer (score 2):

You can properly handle bitmap orientation with ExifInterface.
Please refer to this
[Android Developer Blog post.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/introducing-the-exifinterface-support-library.html)