# How to rotate image after capture from camera

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, android-camera

Issues facing on **Samsung**, when I am capturing the image, the captured image get rotated. I am trying to rotate the image in the vertical direction 90 degree. On Back Facing the image get rotated with below code. But two images get stored on the device. Also issues facing while I am capturing the image on front face the image get rotated, how I can handle the image rotation in below code for both the front and back facing. Any ideas ?

```
                    try {
                    upload_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                    large_bitmap = scaleDownLargeImageWithAspectRatio(upload_bitmap);
                    String fileNameLarge = "myapp_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
                    large_bitmap_path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), large_bitmap, fileNameLarge, null);

                    //Start change orientation
                    String device_name = Build.MANUFACTURER;



                  if(device_name.equals("samsung"))
                   {
                        int rotate=0;
                   try {

                       String realPath = getRealPathFromUri(CameraActivity.this, Uri.parse(large_bitmap_path));
                       exif = new ExifInterface(realPath);
                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
                        switch (orientation) {
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                rotate = 270;
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                rotate = 180;
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                rotate = 90;
                                break;
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                                break;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(90);

                  large_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(large_bitmap, 0, 0, large_bitmap.getWidth(), large_bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

                    horizontalList.add(large_bitmap_path);
                    horizontal_rv.smoothScrollBy(1000, 10);
                    sqLiteHelper.insertPath(large_bitmap_path, "jpg", "fileName");

                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a

Comment: @ADM I followed the these tutorial but dosen't work in my case, can you please give a look on above?

Answer (score 1):

use this library from git hub it handles all these thing related to image [library link](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Comment: This library is only for cropping the image nothing related to above problem.

Comment: it will automatically handle the image rotation problem

Comment: @ hamza khan how I can delete the image in above problem two images are get inserted in gallery.