# Why does an image captured using gallery intent gets rotated on some devices on Android?

Tags: java, android, rotation, image-rotation

I want to take a photo from the gallery and display it with correct rotation.
After a lot of searching, I came up with a solution that unfortunately did not work for me and again, the rotation is wrong.
This method of mine always returns zero.
For your convenience, I have summarized the codes

capture image from gallery:

```
 Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(pickPhoto, 1)
```

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    //          imgProfile.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                    try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                        imgProfile.setImageBitmap(modifyOrientation(bitmap, data.getData().getPath()));

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

```
public static Bitmap modifyOrientation(Bitmap bitmap, String image_absolute_path) throws IOException {
        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(image_absolute_path);
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
        Log.i("TESTETS", "" + orientation);


        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = null;
        switch (orientation) {

            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                rotatedBitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
            default:
                rotatedBitmap = bitmap;
        }
        Log.i("TESTETS", "rotated" + rotatedBitmap);
        return rotatedBitmap;

    }
```

```
 public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does an image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-does-an-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-on-a)

Comment: @FelixFavourChinemerem look at my codes i used that solution but it didn't work

Comment: According to the answer, it says "Note that the below solution depends on the camera software/device manufacturer populating the Exif data, so it will work in most cases, but it is not a 100% reliable solution."

Comment: @FelixFavourChinemerem Okay. But can you introduce a solution that works on all devices?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't. At least, for now.=

Comment: @blackapps Log.i("TESTETS", "" + orientation); always oriantion is 0

Comment: @blackapps                         imgProfile.setImageBitmap(modifyOrientation(bitmap, data.getData().getPath()));

Comment: @blackapps data.getData().getPath() is image_absolute_path

Comment: `data.getData().getPath()` That does not give a file system path. It gives a path that does not exist. Please tell the value.

Comment: "/external/images/media/219" value of data.getData().getPath();  @blackapps

Comment: ok how can I get image_absolute_path?@blackapps

Comment: @blackapps could you please gime me codes?

Comment: InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());  ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(is);

Comment: @blackapps did you mean this?check comment

Comment: @blackapps coud you please edit my codes and put your answer in and then post that?becuase i don't know what should I do

Comment: `Uri image_absolute_path` My god./.. I did not see that you used an uri now. Change the name please as it is coonfusing! `Uri uri`. OK. Now... what is the problem?

Comment: @blackapps eerors:      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V in class Landroid/media/ExifInterface; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.media.ExifInterface' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)

Comment: It is only usable on devices from Android 7 i think. What are your  compileSdkVersion and  targetSdkVersion ? Put them on 30.