# Camera capture image rotate to portrait - Xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a xamarin.android project which have a custom camera Preview. Whenever I initialize the camera , it will open as landscape default. So I changed the orientation from `SurfaceChanged` method like this.

```
private int setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity mContext, int v)
        {
            var degrees = 0;
            var orientation =0;

            Display display = mContext.GetSystemService(Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>().DefaultDisplay;

            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.GetCameraInfo(v, info);
            var rotation = windowManager.DefaultDisplay.Rotation;

            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            display.GetMetrics(dm);
            int width = dm.WidthPixels;
            int height = dm.HeightPixels;

            //Natural orientation is portrait
            if ((rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0 || rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180) && height > width ||
                (rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90 || rotation == SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270) && width > height)
            {
                switch (rotation)
                {
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation0:
                        degrees = 90;
                        break;
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation90:
                        degrees = 0;
                        break;
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation180:
                        degrees = 270;
                        break;
                    case SurfaceOrientation.Rotation270:
                        degrees = 180;
                        break;
                }
            }
            
            return (degrees);
        }
```

It works fine. It will arrange both front and back camera in portrait.

**The problem**

When I capture photo, in some devices, it will store in landscape mode in some devices it will store portrait. I want the image to be in portrait mode no matter what. In order do that I tried to get the `Exif` data of image and rotate it to portrait mode accordingly. But in some devices like samsung, VIVO the orientation value gets as "0". I don't know what to do with that value. If I `PreRotate` 90 , then some devices will solve this issue, while other will save the photo upwards.

```
**Managing Rotation**

 Android.Graphics.Bitmap loadAndResizeBitmap(string filePath)
    {

        Android.Graphics.Bitmap resizedBitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(filePath);
        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try
        {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
            string orientation = exif.GetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagOrientation);

            Android.Graphics.Matrix matrix = new Android.Graphics.Matrix();
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case "1":
                    matrix.PreRotate(-90);
                    resizedBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height, matrix, false);
                    matrix.Dispose();
                    matrix = null;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    matrix.PreRotate(180);
                    resizedBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height, matrix, false);
                    matrix.Dispose();
                    matrix = null;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    matrix.PreRotate(180);
                    resizedBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height, matrix, false);
                    matrix.Dispose();
                    matrix = null;
                    break;
                case "5":
                    matrix.PreRotate(90);
                    resizedBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height, matrix, false);
                    matrix.Dispose();
                    matrix = null;
                    break;
                case "6": // portrait
                    matrix.PreRotate(90);
                    resizedBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height, matrix, false);
                    matrix.Dispose();
                    matrix = null;
                    break;
                case "7":
                    matrix.PreRotate(-90);
                    resizedBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height, matrix, false);
                    matrix.Dispose();
                    matrix = null;
                    break;
                case "8":
                    matrix.PreRotate(-90);
                    resizedBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height, matrix, false);
                    matrix.Dispose();
                    matrix = null;
                    break;
                case "0":
                    matrix.PreRotate(-90);
                    resizedBitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(resizedBitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height, matrix, false);
                    matrix.Dispose();
                    matrix = null;
                    break;
            }

            return resizedBitmap;

        }

        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

I got this Idea from [Xamarin.Andoid Image rotation](https://riptutorial.com/xamarin-android/example/22750/how-to-correct-the-orientation-of-a-picture-captured-from-android-device). But somehow I cant relay on it. What will be the problem? Should I pass Stream instead of file path? Does it due to the surfaceview rotation? How can I make the captured image portrait no matter what on any device? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Personally I've never seen a single solution that covers all the camera orientation issues across all Android devices. The biggest (IHO) is that some phones have rotated sensors and some use "auto-orientation" and to avoid those issues you have to check the orientation BEFORE the capture and use camera parameters to rotate the orientation.

Comment: @SushiHangover Hi thanks for the reply. Can you little explain it? Should I save the images exif data with camera orientation?

Comment: There are lots of Java/Kotlin based solutions that show how this is done properly. I personally use the react-native extensions as my goto source as their developer community is HUGE and know that their `react-native-camera` plug-in handles this issue correctly, as I have borrowed many pieces of that Java to convert to C#, if you search within the issues on that plugin, you will find references to code corrections that handle the orientation properly (of course there are still phones out there that you have to special case per model number if you need 100% compliance)

Comment: which nugget are you using?

Comment: @Blu You mean xamarin.forms version?

Comment: no, i mean the nugget package to capture image & store? do you use any? like `media.plugin` .... search about it

Comment: @Blu Hi, I am not using media plugin, because I want to open the camera view inside my content page.

Comment: okay, np... i will shared my code sample which works perfectly for me, you can give it a try

Comment: @Blu Oh that will be very helpfull. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Only for Xamarin.Android, call it in shared project using dependency service

Get the Angle of rotation of image by this.

```
public int GetImageRotation(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(filePath);
                Orientation orientation = (Orientation)ei.GetAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TagOrientation, (int)Orientation.Undefined);
                switch (orientation)
                {
                    case Orientation.Rotate90:
                        return 90;
                    case Orientation.Rotate180:
                        return 180;
                    case Orientation.Rotate270:
                        return 270;
                    default:
                        return 0;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Now Rotate the image according to the angle value you get.

> I perform operation on stream rather than the actual file & return in the form of Byte array.

```
public byte[] RotateImage(System.IO.Stream imageStream, string filePath)
        {
            int rotationDegrees = GetImageRotation(filePath)
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[imageStream.Length];
            try
            {
                imageStream.Read(byteArray, 0, (int)imageStream.Length);

                Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.PostRotate((float)rotationDegrees);

                Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(originalImage, 0, 0, originalImage.Width,
                    originalImage.Height, matrix, true);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    rotatedBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, ms);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return byteArray;
            }
        }
```

Let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: okay sure, hope it will work for you as well. (We had problem with Samsung Galaxy s7,s8,s9... the above code fixed it)

Comment: Hi, Have one doubt. Should I pass filepath or file name  in  " ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(fileName);"  Is it filename?

Comment: file path... sry for late, i was offline, did you tried it? it worked or not?

Comment: Hi, I tested your code. But now image getting saved on rotated to 90 degree left.  :(

Comment: Does this have any connection to my rotation of surface view?

Comment: Iam getting oreinetation as  Android.Media.Orientation.Undefined.

Comment: yeah maybe, it's cuz of your surface view

Comment: Hi, When we capture image, before rotating the photo taken on front camera is 90 degree left rotated and photo taken on back camera is 90 degree right rotated. so Our code will fail on one case. Did you faced this issue?