# tesseract ocr doesn't works with androidx.camera

Tags: android, camera, tesseract, android-camera2, android-camera-intent

i builded an andoid application with a camera view, using the androidx.camera packages. So, the app shows the camera stream, take a picture with a button and read the picture text with tesseract. The problem is that tesseract doesn't recognize the text of the image (it returns just nosense characters), but, if i take the same photo using a normal camera photo intent, tesseract works perfectly and recognize the text. So, if anyone knows what the problem could be i appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I already found what the problem is. The problem was about the camera orientation. Turns out androidx.camera produced pictures with other orientation than the android camera app. So, tesseract recognized the camera app pictures but it didn't the androidx.camera pictures. I found the solution to this problem, by handling the picture bitmap rotation, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14066265/14040995